# Using one Firebase account for two apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am building a small mobile app using Ionic and Firebase.

What I am trying to do is build one very light app for regular use and another for admin use. The app works in an emulator. I am able to post to the database, edit and everything else. However I can't seem to log in to the admin app. I don't know how to set it up. What I did now:

- created a new account in Firebase
- used the credentials from the original account to connect to database

Now I get an error 10 after clicking the login with Google button.

```
  googleLogin(): void {
    this.googlePlus.login({
      'webClientId': 'XXX',
      // 'offline': true
    }).then(res => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
        .then(success => {
          console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
          this.user = success;
          // this.doLoginStuff(success);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.code === "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential") {
            this.presentToast(error.message)
          }
          console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error))
        });
    }).catch(err => console.error("Error: ", err));
  }
```

I tried accessing the app without login, but the Firebase rules won't allow non authenticated users read or write. This is unclear to me, if my admin app uses the second Firebase account, the user will never be logged in to the original Firebase account and never have read or write access in the database. Not to mention that some lists allow specific users write access.

I even tried coping the `google-services.json` file from the original Firebase account to the admin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you want to create two different apps in the same Firebase project, and use their separate google-services.json files in each one.

Comment: I did create an additional Android app, but it was giving an error when I added the SHA1 code. Is this how  I can solve my problem? By creating another Android app in Firebase and using the new json file?